# New popup window is smaller than intended in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup, window.open

I've got a bug report that the course is opened in smaller popup.

JS to open the popup is:

```
course_window=window.open(urlString,"",
    "toolbar=0,directories=0,location=0,status=0,
    menubar=0,fullscreen=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=1,
    width=1280,height=853,left=0,top=0");
```

and it works but for some random users it opens way to small, like a 3/4, is there any known bug in IE that manifests similarly (popup is opened in different size than passed as arguments in window.open)?

I know that if popup with the same name is already opened than new window.open call will use this to open URL but will ignore any new window feature setup.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on that IE option?

Comment: I'm sorry, looks like the option I was thinking about, is not exactly for this. It rather prevents scripts to create too small windows, or windows out of the screen. Which IE version has been reported?

Comment: I think it was IE10 judging by a screengrab

Answer (score 0):

There is the "Box model bug" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug)
Inspect the element and check if border or padding affect the size.